Proof of the curvature of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $0$

The curvature $R$ of a Riemannian manifold $M$ is a correspondence that associates to every pair $X,Y\in \mathcal{X}(M) $ a mapping $R(X,Y): \mathcal{X}(M)\to \mathcal{X}(M)$ given by $$R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_X\nabla_YZ+\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$$ where $\nabla$ is the Riemannian connection of $M$.

By writing $X=x_iX_i$ and $Z=z_jX_j=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ where $X_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, we find that $\nabla_{X}{Z}=x_i\nabla_{X_i}{z_jX_j}=x_i(X_i(z_j)X_j+z_j\gamma_{ij}^{k}X_k)=x_iX_i(z_j)X_j=X(z_j)X_j$.
$\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ=(YXz_1,\ldots,YXz_n)$. $[X,Y]=XY-YX=x_iX_iy_jX_j-y_iX_ix_jX_j$.
Thus, $\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z=x_iX_iy_jX_jz_kX_k-y_iX_ix_jX_jz_kX_k=[XY(z_k)-YX(z_k)]X_k$.
$R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_X\nabla_YZ+\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Question: Everything goes well except $x_iz_j\gamma_{ij}^{k}X_k=0$(i.e $\gamma_{ij}^{k}=0$), how can I compute this one in $\mathbb{R}^n$? I know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}$. Thank you for your help.

Those $\gamma_{ij}^k$ are the Christoffel symbols https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols$ which in the Euclidean space are known to be zero for the Levi-Civita connection. There are many ways to find them, I link the following link which I find very useful https://www.akalin.com/curvature-moving-frames

Notice that you only need the metric and in your case $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$.

@user57 Thank you for providing these materials! I can understand it this way, but I saw a video, and the teacher just wrote down this result without any explanation, is that obvious?

The Euclidean space having zero curvature I believe it is very straightforward. The proof of this, is a matter of finding the Christoffel symbols which from the second link becomes apparent. In fact, if you want to find the curvature of any space you first provide a metric and then do exactly the same thing.

@user57 Again, thank you for your reply!
